# Is XLConnect in R is vectorized for writeNamedRegion()? What is the syntax for it?

Tags: vectorization, xlconnect

I want to write to NamedRegions in multiple sheets in an excel workbook using XLConnect from R using vectorization, if possible.

I have a list:
trya
$grp1
        var1 var2 var3
1455100  459   21  459

$grp2
       var1 var2 var3
936710  463   20  463

I have a workbook template (wb1) containing a worksheet (Sheet1) that contains namedRegions (each a single cell). The namedRegions in Sheet1 are named : "varn1","varn2","varn3"

I can clone Sheet1 to create separate sheets to contain the data for each grp in trya.

cloneSheet(wb1, sheet="Sheet1", name = names(trya))

But..how do I write to the NamedRegions in these sheets? I am happy to use 3 separate passes, one for each NamedRegion to write to the multiple worksheets.
Here is my start at the code for NamedRegion "varn1: using code
example is writeNamedRegion(object,data,name of region,header,rownames)

writeNamedRegion(wb1, trya??? ,name = "varn1",header = FALSE)

I don't know 
1. how to generically pick off the elements of trya like: trya[[1]]$var1?
2. how to loop over the cloned sheets, named.... names(trya)?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Many of XLConnect's functions/methods are vectorized. This also holds for `writeNamedRegion`. The following example illustrates how to write a `list` of `data.frame`'s to appropriate named regions using a single `writeNamedRegion` call:

```
require(XLConnect)

wb = loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create = TRUE)

mySheets = paste0("MySheet", 1:3)
myNames = paste0("MyName", 1:3)
myData = list(mtcars, CO2, USArrests)

createSheet(wb, name = mySheets)
createName(wb, name = myNames, formula = paste(mySheets, "$A$1", sep = "!"))

writeNamedRegion(wb, data = myData, name = myNames)

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much!  Jan

Comment: My problem is a little more complex and I can't generalize the answer.   I